# Cursor payload is too big compared to the useful payload

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

**Steps to reproduce**

The logic of the application assumes that there are number of data sources on the server which are handled by groups.
If client wants to subscribe to the specific data source, it calls:

```
myhub.Subscribe(dataSourceId);
```

On the server side, we just add the client to the specific group:

```
await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, dataSourceId.ToString());
```

Then all the messages are sent with huge cursor payload. And the most important part, the size of it grows with every subscription.

[image]

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**
Similar: [SignalR and large number of groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651169/signalr-and-large-number-of-groups)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is how cursors work. Cursor contains references to all topics the connection is subscribed to and each group is a separate topic. Besides the cursor getting bigger there is one more limitation to using many groups. The more groups the client is a member of the bigger the groups token. The groups token is sent back to the server when the client is reconnecting and if it gets too big it may exceed the URL size limit causing reconnect failures.

Comment: I found a similar issue(updated the question). Guys over there suggest to manage groups manually and send updates per connection. I guess this would work but as far as I understood there will be no way to resubscribe to those groups in case of re-connection. Is it a valid approach?